# Ransack search not working in rails model but working fine in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a problem with Ransack. Here is my Search Form

```
= search_form_for @query, :url => search_products_path, :html => { :method => :get } do |f|
    %dl.left
      %dl.left
        %dt= f.label :sku, t('shoppe.orders.sku')
        %dd= f.text_field :with_sku
      %dl.right
        %dt= f.label :name, t('shoppe.products.name')
        %dd= f.text_field :with_translated_name
```

and my model code for searching is

```
def self.with_sku(sku_string)
      sku_string = sku_string.squish
      where("LOWER(shoppe_products.sku) LIKE ?" , "%#{sku_string}%".downcase)
end
```

So. Problem is SKU search is not working when a number field is entered and converted to string but it is working fine when this is done in rails console. Any help would be loved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a problem with some of my associations. I updated them and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I think squish is a string method. I get errors when trying to call it on an integer:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `squish' for 245:Integer
```

Just to be safe, explicitly cast your search value to a String first, then it should work:

```
str = str.to_s.squish
```

Comment: It was actually a problem with some of my associations. I updated them and it is working fine. Thank You Andrew :)